# How to merge a commit into an earlier commit?

Tags: git

I have made 3 commits (A, B, C):

```
$ git log -3 --pretty=oneline
64ffaf1ec379150cb423844bfff7557704c92a4e C
bf89fa3c27dfb9eb3d4c0d83f268902fa828d986 B
a9cae79f45c2494909ff64246182d6a4fde51eda A
```

How to merge C commit into A commit?

I want to keep commit B, which would reflect changes in now merged A and C commit.

I am aware that I can merge a commit into a previous commit using git rebase. But I don't know how to merge a specific commit into an earlier commit and rewrite the change history.

Comment: if you just want to merge commit C into A use cherrypick. But why not just move to A and `git merge C`?

Comment: @iberbeu That wouldn't remove git from the git log. The reason for wanting this is to keep the git log clean (thats literally the only reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "merge" you mean "combine" rather than the technical usage of "merge" in git.  In that case, `git rebase --interactive` is your friend.  Running that will bring up your editor with the following content:

```
pick a9cae79 A
pick bf89fa3 B
pick 64ffaf1 C
```

You will want to change this to something like the following:

```
pick a9cae79 A
squash 64ffaf1 C
pick bf89fa3 B
```

Then save and quit your editor.  This will combine the changes from commits A and C, then prompt you to edit the commit message, pre-populated with the commit messages from commits A and C.  Alternatively, if you want to discard the commit message from commit C, use `fixup` instead of `squash` in the above.

Comment: Thats awesome. I did not realise that I case change order of git commits when performing interactive rebase.